# How to hide URL Selector content tab?

Tags: kentico

I am creating a custom webpart using the **Url Selector** from kentico. I want the user to select content just from the Media Library. I went to `form controls -> Url Selector -> Properties -> Dialogs_Content_Hide -> Default Value -> Yes` and it still showing it in the Web Part. If I select the `Dialogs_Web_Hide`, `Dialogs_Libraries_Hide` and select the yes option in the default values, they hide, all except the Content_Dialogs.

Is this a bug? Or its something wrong?

[Here is an example of the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW93V.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the form controls properties back to the way they were. If you don't, it will cause all kinds of problems later on.

Secondly, when you create the property in the webpart in the UI, select the URL selector form control for your text fields control. The scroll down just a bit and under the Editing Control Settings you'll see an "Configure" link. Click it. In there you will be able to tell the form control what tabs you want to enable and disable.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Brenden's answer; if this is something you need to do a lot for your current build, then I'd also suggest making a copy of the Url selector form control and customize the properties as you originally mentioned.  This way, you leave the default control in place for the system and have a control tailored to your needs.  I've done this just now to check with a  new form control that I called **Media URL selector**. Do make sure that you select the same source file as the original control in the *Cloned form control file name* property - Kentico by default will try to locate a new file called `<original filename>_1.ascx`. The reason for this is that admin section of your site also makes use of this control, so you may cause a nasty side effect somewhere else in the system.

As for why the settings had no effect; these are the default values you are setting.  If you already have the form control in use, then the default setting would have been applied as they originally were.  If you find one of the fields in question, you can change the control type to *Text box*, click *Save*, and then reassign it to *Media URL selector*.

Comment: Thats a great idea!! Thanks so much mnield!  I will implement this option for sure!